# How can I type with Chinese characters in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, localization, adobe-premiere, input-languages, charset

I have a standard US version of Windows 7. I would like to input Chinese characters in Adobe Premier Pro. How can I do this?

Comment: Does the standard IME not work in Premiere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable typing in Chinese on Windows, this is how I enable it (works on past versions of Windows- not sure about Windows 7, but could be helpful for other users on Superuser):

1. Start Menu > Control Panel > Regional and Language Options
2. Select the "Language" Tab
3. Check the box that says "Install files for East Asian Language"
4. Select "Apply" After the files have been install,
5. Right click on the Toolbar, Select Toolbars > Language Bar
6. Click on the arrow for the Language bar and select "Settings"
7. In the "Text Services and Input Language box" Select "Chinese (PRC) and select "Add"
8. In the "Add Input Language," check make sure "Chinese (PRC)" is selected and check the "Keyboard layout/IME" box (I select Simplified, "Microsoft Pinyin IME")
9. Click "OK"
10. Click "Apply"

See this link for a visual of steps:

[image]

Now a box should appear in your Toolbar with "EN" in it. Click that box to select "Chinese (PRC)"
**太好了！**

**NOTE:** *Shortcut!!* If you to swtich between English and Chinese without selecting the box, Press: CTRL + SPACE BAR. Its very nice for making changes on the fly.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you need the keyboard to type Simplified Chinese, without having to download anything, see if your Win7 Pro/Home Premium already has Chinese.

- Go to Control Panel/Clock, Language, and Region/Region and Language/Change keyboards or other input methods.
- to the "Keyboards and Languages" tab, click "Change Keyboards..." button.
- In to "General" tab and in the "Installed Services" section, click the "Add.." button.
- Then select the Chinese language you want ie. Chinese (Simplified, PRC).

Click OK.  Your keyboard should now be ready for Simplied Chinese input.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, [configure the IME](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/windows-7/win7-chinese-intro.htm). This should allow you to use Hanzi in most applications.